# I want to see if event is initialized or not but get an error

Tags: java, android, initialization

I have 2 classes, 1st being `Sprite` and 2nd being `GameView`. I have a `onTouchEvent` in the GameView class and I want to change the sprites direction and animation upon a touchevent. However, any way I have tried to address the event in the sprite class I get a `Variable might not have been initialized` so therefor I want to check if the event is initialized - this gives me the same error though!

Sprite class:

```
    MotionEvent event;  // These three declarations is just to get them in
    int xcoords;        // the scope - not sure it's the right way.
    int ycoords;

    if (gameView.onTouchEvent(event, xcoords, ycoords) != null) {  // This
    // gives me the error, specifically on event, xcoords and ycoords.

        MotionEvent event = this.gameView.onTouchEvent(event.getPointerCount());
        int isPushedDown = event.getPointerCount();

        if (isPushedDown == 0) {

            srcX = 1;
            srcY = 3;

            Rect srcNoMove = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX, srcY);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, srcNoMove, dst, null);

        }

    }
```

GameView event:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, float xcoord, float ycoord) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 500) {
            lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    xcoord = event.getX();
    ycoord = event.getY();

    return onTouchEvent(event, xcoord, ycoord);

}
```

How do I address this problem? 
Declaring the variables above with `null`, and 2 times `= 0;` gives the problem that a Boolean cant be null and doing `if (!gameView.onTouchEvent(event)) {` would that not just return the null I stated above?

I want to check if the variable is initiated and if it is, do something.

Comment: `These three declarations is just to get them in  the scope` - what do you mean?

Comment: I got an error saying they weren't in the scope so that's why I declared them-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that there's a difference between a variable being *uninitialized* and a variable being *initialized* but having a value of `null`. If a variable is uninitialized (like `event,` `xcoords`, and `ycoords` in your question), you can't use it for *anything*, including checking it for a `null` value. You must ensure that the variable is initialized to some value before you use it in any way.

Comment: I am with you so far but my problem is that I don't know the proper way to check if the variable has been initialized or not so the method id `!= null` was from another post with the same error, just a variable in the same class.

Comment: You can't programmatically check whether a variable is initialized. You must ensure that it absolutely will be initialized by constructing your code with that in mind.

Comment: Ah that is what you meant! Okay. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the `Variable might not be initialized` you can declare an object with an initial value of `null` and then later test for a null (like `if(object != null)`).

It is a different story with primitives, as they cannot be null. However, there are classes built in to Java that use these primitives as bases.

You can change `int xcoords` to be `Integer xcoords = null`. It will then have a value of null, and you can appropriately test for nulls using the syntax I described above.

Java has classes like this for every primitive. `int` is `Integer`, `boolean` is `Boolean`, etc. Most of them should be easy to figure out.

Comment: When I do this it comes with the error of checking `!=` against a Boolean - that would in my mind say it has been initialized, or?

Comment: With objects (and not primitives), you are not supposed to use the '==' or '!=' operator. If you have a variable 'b' that is of type 'Boolean', you can check for nulls by writing 'if(!b.equals(anotherBoolean)'

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all.

```
MotionEvent event = this.gameView.onTouchEvent(event.getPointerCount());
```

Bad practice.

---

Secondary

```
if (gameView.onTouchEvent(event, xcoords, ycoords) != null) {
```

Bad practice. onTouchEvent must return boolean result. Not a object.

---

### However.

You need initialize a variable before using. *"VERY SMART"* Java compiler get error to you because most probably you have `NullPointerException` in runtime.

```
MotionEvent event;

if(event.getX() != 0f) // compile error.
```

FIX :

```
MotionEvent event = null; // In good case - you need use obtain(...) method of MotionEvent class.

if(event!=null && event.getX() != 0f) // All ok.
```

Comment: How would you change the first then? I need event to be taken from the other class.

Comment: In good case you don't need to send event thought classes. You need detect touch in Sprite class. If you need some information from GameView class - just set it when app initialized.(in OnCreate() for ex.)

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing this man - this (in my head) seems like the right solution. 
So, just to clarify. In the `onCreate()` I specify (pseudo) sprite needs knowledge of gameview. and it will automatically know about the onTouchevent?

Comment: Or should I detect the touch even in the sprite class?

Comment: @Evilunclebill yes. You should. Thinking : Android have many layouts - FrameLayout, LinearLayout, Relative, etc. In this layouts may exist several views. If all touches handle by parent - it will be bad for performance. Why? Because before send touch we need find item-receiver. And lets suppose. In one layout 100 views. Each touch to last view - 100 loops before we can find item-receiver. Bad, very bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

First there is not enough code posted to tell exactly what is happening, and the rest of code is rather bad and I just cannot even imagine what you are trying to do here and what was your actual problem. Maybe your first draft code before you tried to fix it in wrong way would be more telling.

```
gameView.onTouchEvent(event, xcoords, ycoords) != null
```

In above code you are not actually comparing whether your `onTouchEvent` is assigned in above code, you are calling it, and since its return value is `boolean` you cannot compare it with `null`

If `gameView` is instance of `GameView` class, then you don't have to check whether your event is initialized (actually, it is not event but method of your `GameView` class) and you can use it if `gameView` variable is initialized. So quite possible is that you actually want to test `gameView != null`

Also your `GameView` `onTouchEvent` method is calling itself recursively with `return onTouchEvent(event, xcoord, ycoord);`

---

While you do have issues with your code, real problem here seems to be that you want to go forward way to fast, and you are trying to skip learning the basics. Another issue is that when you bump into an issue, you are listening to compiler trying to purely satisfy its errors without considering what you are actually doing. Compilers are stupid, don't let them lead the way. You are the boss here.

So when compiler tells you that you don't have variable `event` in scope, you have to stop and think what is the actual meaning. Do you really need `event` variable there or not? If you just forgot declaring it, then go ahead and do it, but if this kind of error (or any other error) has caught you by surprise then you have to stop and rethink your steps.

Now back to some basics.

```
public class GameView
{
   // onTouchEvent is method of GameView class
   // it can only be called on valid (non-null) instance of GameView class
   // when you have valid instance of GameView class all its methods 
   // can be used, you don't have to check whether they are null 
   //
   // return value of onTouchEvent is declared as boolean and that 
   // is the only value it can possibly return
   // passed parameters are event, xcoord and ycoord and they can be used inside 
   // onTouchEvent the way you see fit. 
   // since event is object (depending on class design) you can change its state and 
   // those changes will be preserved after onTouchEvent finishes. 
   // xcoord and ycoord are primitive types passed as value and whatever 
   // you do to them those changes will not survive after onTouchEvent.

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, float xcoord, float ycoord) 
   {         
      xcoord = event.getX(); // this value will be lost the moment onTouchEvent returns
      return true; // or return false 
   }

}
```

First question in your classes design is what exactly should happen when user touches the screen. Does your `Sprite` has to react on touch events that only happen when actual `Sprite` location is touched, or it has to react no matter where touch occurred. In first case the best course of action would be to implement touch detection directly inside `Sprite` class. In second case, you have to implement touch detection inside `GameView` class and then direct your sprite instance to do something.

I am assuming that both `Sprite` and `GameView` are extending `View` class so we can tap in into default touch event dispatching overriding `onTouchEvent` method.

First way - process touch inside `Sprite`. In this case GameView does not need to know anything about `Sprite` and does not need `Sprite` instance

```
public class Sprite extends View
{
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            // do your movement logic
            return true; // return true if we are handling the event, false otherwise
        }
}
```

Second way - do your touch processing in `GameView`. In this case `GameView` has to hold valid `Sprite` instance

```
public class Sprite extends View
{
    public void move(float x, float y)
    {
    // do your movement logic here 
    }
} 

public class GameView extends View
{
    public Sprite sprite; // you have to initialize that sprite instance before you can use it 
    // - most likely in Activity onCreate method, but that will depend on your game logic

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        sprite.move(event.GetX(), event.GetY());
        return true; // return true if we are handling the event, false otherwise
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for bad coding, I've been trying self-teaching by doing as that holds my interest the most. 
I'm not sure what you mean by the last?
I posted this amount as I thought it was sufficient, its only those to methods that is used in the problem.

Comment: Calling recursively means that code will produce infinite loop.

Comment: You don't have to apologize for writing bad code, I was just trying to say that it is hard to give you more help because it is hard to tell what you are doing from your code.

Comment: Aha, and result in stackoverflow? How do I return the coordinates then? As said above via. the onCreate()?

Comment: It would help having class declaration, with its constructor, you can most likely omit getters and setters methods unless, you have some deeper logic in them (and if you have any). also it is unknown how your `Sprite` knows about `gameView`, from where it comes from.

Comment: What `onCreate` are you talking about? `onCreate` is usually something that happens once when you are creating some object, not something that will return coordinates for touch events. What you can do in some `onCreate` method is connect your dependent objects. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstand you. I was thinking about the `onCreate()` that is in mainActivity

Comment: I added some additional code and explanations that might help you get started. But above all, when something goes wrong, don't panic, go back and rethink your design and logic without thinking in terms of code, and don't be afraid to delete bad code and rewrite everything if it does not feel right. Also, when you ask for help, use the first version of code where you encountered error, because most likely result of unsuccessful attempts to fix things would be more messy than original code.

Comment: Thank you for this lesson. I will try to take it into practice!